# SQL-What is wrong with my timestamp?

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is my timestamp without a timezone.

`2016-03-26,23.59.03

The problem is I have a error which specifies that "syntax error at or near ".03"
I don't understand this, can someone help me? thanks.

I am using PostgreSQL.

Comment: 2016-03-26 23:59:03

Comment: It says "syntax error at or near "23"

Comment: Could you post the entire SQL statement where you are using it?

Comment: If postgre understands [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) `2016-03-26T23:59:03` should work.

Comment: "syntax error at or near "T23"

Comment: So you have a timestamp and all you want to do with it is stating it?! What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: you have a wrong comma between 26 and 23

Comment: Yes, I want a timestamp without a time zone, that's it

Comment: So it's supposed to be the value of a field I guess?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: VALUES (7234,2016-03-26T23:59:03,'OHIO','PHILADELPHIA',800,1200.00);

Comment: See my answer- good chance you just miss the second `'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date format and subtract 30 days to prove it's interpreted correctly as date format:

```
select date '2017-03-17T20:48:00' -30 AS ts
```

or

```
values('2017-03-17T20:48:00')
```

Works [here](http://rextester.com/l/postgresql_online_compiler)